# Get the value of all the jquery inputs within a fieldset

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

this is the first question i ask here. 
I have a fieldset which has inside 4 inputs. I want to validate the form if at least 2 of 4 are completed. I can get the value of the first input with `$("#communications input").val()`.

```
 <fieldset class="input-group-fieldset bigger-labels" id="communications">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns twelve">
            <div class="input-group" id="pref-mail-wrap">
                <label>Email Address</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrefferedEmail, new { @class = "contact-group" })

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns four">
            <div class="input-group" id="pref-phone-wrap">
                <label>Telephone No</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrefferedPhoneNo, new { @class = "contact-group" })



            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns four">
            <div class="input-group" id="pref-sms-wrap">
                <label>SMS No</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrefferedSmsNo, new { @class = "contact-group" })

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="" id="pref-address-wrap">

        <div class="row fixed-width">
            <div class="columns twelve">
                <div class="input-group2">
                    <label>Address </label>

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostalAddress)

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Thank you in advance,
Kostas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) as below.

```
var $completedInputs = $("#communications input:text").filter(function() {
    //return the ones witn non-empty values
    return $.trim(this.value) != "";
});

if ($completedInputs.length >= 2) {
    //At least 2 inputs have been filled.   
}
```

`$("#communications input:text")` or `$("#communications :text")` => All inputs whose type is text

`$("#communications input")` => All inputs

Comment: Thank you. This actually helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `name` attribute for all these `input` elements, then serialize them and check it using:

```
if($('#communications :input').serializeArray().length >=2)
```

`'#communications input'` would be enough in your case

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. All of my inputs have a name. When i use the code you provided me, it returns true no matter how many of the inputs are empty or not.

Comment: @KostasArva It won't serialize input with no value, post minimalistic sample replicating your issue or at least the rendered HTML markup in browser. Maybe you have other kind of `:input`, not only textbox, then try: `$('#communications :text').serializeArray().length`. Be aware, any wite space in textbox makes it valid regarding form HTML5 validation, it could be your issue too but i doubt about it

Comment: At least i had this figured out. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery each() for selectors returning more then 1 elements:

```
$("#communications input").each(function(){
   // $(this).val(); check here what you want.
})
```

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
var count = 0;
$('#communications input').each(function(index, item) {
    if($(item).val()!=="") {
        count ++;
    }
    return count <= 2; // break; if more than 2 have values
    });

if(count >= 2) {
    //valid
}
```

Read more at:
https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to check how many of the `inputs` have been given a value. Try this:

```
var validInputs = $("#communications input").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).val().trim() == '';
}).length;

if (validInputs < 2) {
    // form is invalid...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was helpful as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If all the inputs have the same format and the validation is the same
try to iterate through all the inputs within the `fieldset`

```
$("#communications input").each(function(i,v){

});
```

Otherwise you should validate the 4 inputs individually.

Comment: I already had my validations set. Let's say for example that you left the email field blank. When you hit enter there will be a message telling you to complete it. I just wanted to make you complete the email field and one more. This was the part i couldn't manage! Thank you for your response.

Comment: You could use the jQuery `validation` plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: I am using this plugin to validate my form. I am now trying to create a custom rule in order to validate a form with 8 fields.